# Grep functionality with Git Log command

Tags: git, gerrit

I need to use the Git log command to extract Commit Id, commit subject where commit-body contains a specific word. I also need to print only those lines from the commit body that contain that word.

Using the command below, I am able to obtain relevant commit Id's and subject, but I can't see the lines from commit body containing the word 'CRs-Fixed'.

```
git log --pretty=format:"%H,%s" AU_1..AU2 --no-merges --grep='CRs-Fixed'
```

And If I do `git log --pretty=format:"%H,%s,%b" AU_1..AU2 --no-merges --grep='CRs-Fixed'`,
I get the entire commit body- which I don't need.

Any suggestions on how to get only the desired information?

Answer (score 1):

Tag your header lines as keepers:

> `git log --pretty=format:$'\001%H\n\001%s\n%b' --grep='CRs-Fixed' \` 
>   `| sed $'/^\001\\|Crs-Fixed/s/^\001//'`

Answer (score 0):

Elegance says that there must be a better way, but for now the only solution I can see is to make use of standard `awk` and `grep`.

The following awk script causes the hash to be prepended to all extra body lines:

```
if ($1 ~ /[0-9a-f]{40}/) { h=$1 } else { printf h } print
```

With this we can then grep only the lines we want:

```
git log --pretty='%H,%s,%b' AU_1..AU2 --no-merges --grep='CRs-Fixed' \
    | awk -F, --re-interval '{if($1~/[0-9a-f]{40}/){h=$1}else{printf h}print}' \
    | grep 'CRs-Fixed'
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very elegant, but you could do it in a PowerShell script, like so:

```
function GitGrep {
  param ([string]$range, [string]$grepThis)

  git log --pretty=format:"%H" $range --no-merges --grep="$grepThis" | ForEach-Object {
    $Body = git log -1 --pretty=format:"%b" $_ | Select-String "$grepThis"
    if($Body) {
      git log -1 --pretty=format:"%H,%s" $_
      Write-Host $Body
    }
  }
}
```

Then

```
GitGrep AU_1..AU2 CRs-Fixed
```

Answer (score 0):

Variation on cbuckley's answer:

```
(echo '$VAR1 = ['; \
git log --pretty='[ q(%H), q(%s), q(%b) ],' ; \
echo ']') \
| perl -e '$/=undef; $str = <>; $data = eval $str;
    foreach my $record (@$data) {
        next unless $record->[2] =~ /Scrivener/;
        print $record->[0], "\t", $record->[1], "\n" }'
```

In one of my repositories, this yields the following.

```
e38e7dcd6e87ca08d4163aa7772a1559682b26ad    Ignore unnecessary Scrivener files.
794ececb7643653b0d3920aa6f548a2a9f94c5d6    Add "The Fallen". Changes to "Wirehead".
```

I supposed it's still debatable how elegant this technique is, but it does allow you to build an arbitrary data structure in the language of your choice, and work with it more easily. You could easily build JSON out of git-log, for example, though I used perl's quoting construct above to avoid issues with quotes. You could always build XML or HTML too.